# Can't start ServiceControl when using SqlTransport with multiple databases

Tags: nservicebus, nsb-servicecontrol

I'm getting the following error when trying to start ServiceControl:

> Fatal|NServiceBus|Startup task failed to complete.
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: The transport is running in native SQL Server transactions mode without an outbox, but configuration uses multi-database sending (http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sqlserver/multiple-databases). Multi-database sends can only be used when either in ambient transaction mode or when outbox is enabled. Please check your endpoint configuration.

I'm using SqlTransport with multiple databases. My ServiceControl.exe.config looks like this (omitted the connection strings)

```
<add name="NServiceBus/Transport" connectionString="..." />
<add name="NServiceBus/Transport/EndPointA" connectionString="..." />
```

I followed this article http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sqlserver/multiple-databases which describes setting up the config as I have done, but it's not clear to me what I should do to resolve the issue.

Comment: What version of ServiceControl and NServiceBus are you running? Can you share the complete setup (without the actual connection strings so i can test it? )

Comment: Particular.ServiceControl is 1.8.0.0
NServiceBus 5.2.10

Comment: Can you sen an email to support at particular.net with the code or upload it to github or dropbox so I can test it? Really need to see the code and test it to see if it is a bug...